# Spring Kafka: How does kafkaTemplate executeInTransaction method play with Consumer's read_committed isolation level

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-platform, spring-transactions

I am seeing that the `isolation.level=read_committed` consumer property ensures that only committed messages will be read by the consumer. I am trying to understand what is meant by a `committed message` in this context exactly ? When can we say a producer's message is committed to a topic?

#### My Specific scenario

I am using Spring-kafka, `kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction` method asynchronously to send messages to kafka.

I see `executeInTransaction` method internally calls `producer.commitTransaction()` which in turn throws exception if it cannot complete within `max.block.ms`

#### My Confusion is

if `producer.commitTransaction()` completes within `max.block.ms`, does that mean the message has been stored in the topic successfully, ready for a consumer with `isolation.level=read_committed` to consume?

I ask this because I see there is another property `delivery.timeout.ms` which corresponds to processes that start after `send()`/`max.block.ms` is complete.

**So..** does this mean even after `producer.commitTransaction()` returns, we still need to wait maximum of `delivery.timeout.ms` to be certain that the message has been written to a topic ?

Answer (score 1):

No; when the commit is successful, the record is secure in the log.